# In RubyMine, how do you get it to recognize Cucumber feature files?

Tags: rubymine

I created a new feature file, test.feature, but RubyMine does not recognize it as a cucumber feature file and instead treats it as a simple text file. I can not dig through the file, and it does not receive syntax highlighting.

I have tried deleting and recreating the file, but it still treats it as a simple text file.

How do I get RubyMine to recognize this file as a feature file so I can use the IDE's features on the feature file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Settings | File Types | Cucumber scenario files, make sure *.feature extension is added there.

Comment: Thanks for this, wasn't exactly the solution but it led me to the solution. Apparently my file was set as a Registered Patterns of the Text file type so it wasn't recognized as a Cucumber scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, go to RubyMine > Preferences > IDE Settings > File Types to add Registered Patterns.

Under Cucumber scenario files, check to see if "*.feature" is listed. If not, add it for correct Cucumber syntax highlighting. More information [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/file-types.html).